# Condition to ng-hide if the other case is true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is what the network shows in Chrome:

```
    currently_working: true
    from_date: "2009-02-01"
    to_date: "1971-01-01"
```

How do I apply a condition so that "to_date" is hidden when "currently_working" is true and show when the "currently_working" is false?

```
    <span ng-hide="experience.currently_working == true ? Currently Working : {{experience.to_date  | date:"MMM, yyyy"}}"</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-bind

```html
<span ng-bind="experience.currently_working? 'Currently Working' : experience.to_date  | date:'MMM, yyyy'" ></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-if

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

```
<span ng-if="!experience.currently_working"> {{experience.to_date  | date:"MMM, yyyy"}}"</span>
```

Comment: Thank You. I want to show "Currently Working" when the condition is true. How should I achieve that?

Comment: ng-if="experience.currently_working"  just remove the !

Comment: I didn't want to create two conditions. I wanted to create the condition in one <span>

Comment: Like in my original code, I had mention a condition to show "Currently Working" if it's true else show the date. This is not reflected on your code.